# Telerik Reporting: Adding Textbox at Runtime Does Not Show Up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, runtime, telerik-reporting

I'm currently working on a report using Telerik Reporting (release Q1 2013), and I'm attempting to add a textbox at runtime to a header (and eventually the detail section as well), but the issue is the textbox that gets added does not show up.  I'm not sure why it's not displaying, but there are no errors that occur after it is added.  Right now I'm trying to add it during the itemdatabinding event.  My code is below:

```
public partial class _WellPlateReport : Telerik.Reporting.Report
{
  public _WellPlateReport(Dictionary<string, object> ReportParameters)
  {
    //
    // Required for telerik Reporting designer support
    //
    InitializeComponent();
    tbGenotype.Visible = false;
    //
    // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
    //
  }

  private void labelsGroupHeaderSection_ItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string temp = "";

    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.GroupSection headerGroup = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.GroupSection)sender;

    Telerik.Reporting.TextBox tb = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
    tb.Left = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit(0.5, UnitType.Inch) + tbGenotype.Left +   tbGenotype.Width;
    //tb.Width = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit(3.0, UnitType.Inch);
    tb.Size = tbSex.Size;
    tb.Name = "TestLabel1";
    tb.Value = "Test Label";
    tb.Location = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PointU(tbGenotype.Left + tbGenotype.Width + new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit(0.5, UnitType.Inch), Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0D));

    //this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.Items.Add(tb);
    //this.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.Reporting.ReportItemBase[] { tb });

    this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.Reporting.ReportItemBase[] { tb });
  }
}
```

The tbGenotype is another textbox that the new textbox will be added next to at runtime, so i'm using the positioning of that to place the dynamic textboxes.  There is an unknown number of additional columns that will need to be added, but I'm not sure why this isn't working.  My searches showed others adding controls in a similar way.

Update: Also note, that the textbox tbGenotype was added in the designer in visual studio.  Trying to set the visible property on that works, but adding the textbox to the header does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [this documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/programmatic-creating-controls.html). The only difference that I noticed was that they are adding the textbox to a panel. Then they are adding panel to the report. Check if tbGenotype is added in a panel or not but I think that every element you put in a report has to be in same panel first.

Comment: I checked the documentation there from your link, and I'm basically doing the same thing.  I added the name property and changed the sizing and location, and I can see that the textbox gets added to the items collection, but the control is not visible anywhere on the report in the label header section.

Comment: Update: I updated the telerik reporting DLLs to Q1 2014, and the same problem exists.  The control gets added, but is not visible and does not get rendered.

Comment: Try to add the textbox and then save the template to file. Then open it with designer and see if the textbox is there or not.

Comment: Pepo, I'm not really sure what you mean by saving the template to a file.  All of these reports were created inside of visual studio, not with Telerik's report editor (using the editor inside visual studio).

Comment: This is what I meant [ReportXmlSerializer Class](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/t_telerik_reporting_xmlserialization_reportxmlserializer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I notice when I refresh the report with the refresh button inside the report viewer (in my windows application; should be the same for the web version), the dynamically added controls show up. When I refresh a second time, an additional (second) set of controls shows up.

My observation is this: on initial run, the controls are added, but not visible (regardless of the visible property value being true). On first refresh (second server/application run), a second set of controls is added, not visible, and the first set is now visible. On the second refresh / third run, a third set of not visible controls is added, and the first 2 sets of controls are shown.

First, I need to clear my parent panel(s) of all dynamically added items before adding again. But, to the point of the question, calling *ReportViewerInstance*.RefreshReport() should cause the dynamically added controls to become visible before the initial rendering of the report. I am about to try this scenario. I am not certain yet how I am going to call the instance of the report viewer, but at minimum, I should be able to pass a reference to the instance as a report parameter, or similar.

RefreshReport() call found in [this Telerik help post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-dynamically-item-field-into-report-detail-section):

I will update with my results after trying the above.

UPDATE: RefreshReport did NOT work for me - it cancelled the processing and resulted in no report. However, I did solve my issue. And, it should solve the OP's issue as well.

Eric's code shows trying to create and show the dynamically added controls in an ItemDataBinding event. I was doing the same, and also tried ItemDataBound. Both of these events occur when processing is in action, and a help topic regarding a dynamically added table control tipped me off. The Telerik expert recommended not altering the report items during processing to avoid unpredictable behavior. Following that, I moved my code to create controls into a method (not an event) and call it from my *Report*.NeedDataSource event, after instantiating all needed data objects, and before setting the report datasource as one of my object collections. This works great!

I hope this helps someone else!